# Serverless deploy - Function not found - sls deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy a Serverless function via the Serverless CLI and I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred: GenerateDownloadLinkLambdaFunction - Function not
>   found:

What's strange is that I've deployed this function for another stage `qa` and it deployed fine, but for `dev` it just throws the above error.

If I try to manually create the function from the AWS console and deploy it, the Lambda functions menu shows that the function was deployed X seconds ago, however it does not show any of the settings I have in my `serverless.yml` file on my machine.

It's also worth noting that I had managed to have this function deployed on the `dev` stage but I accidentally deleted it. Since then it refuses to redeploy.

Have been banging my head against the wall as to what I'm doing wrong but can't spot anything, has anyone else encountered a similar issue with Serverless before?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I’ve faced this issue with Serverless. The issue is caused by how Serverless handles, tracks, and deploys your functions. When you deleted the function you effectively changed the state of your application manually, and it is effectively out of sync.

To resolve this, comment out the function that is refusing to deploy, and run `sls deploy`. When its finished uncomment the function, and `sls deploy` again. This time it should deploy your function.

Comment: I had eventually just renamed the function but sounds like this is the same effect. THanks!

Comment: The solution from Tamojit Chakraborty with `sls remove` (below) is much cleaner than just removing `sls deploy` and putting it back

Comment: That really depends. A full `sls remove` will remove all resources in a stack, including log groups, the API gateway etc. This can be problematic in many scenarios. For example, if you have compliance obligations and need to retain the logs, or if you have the API gateway mapped to a custom domain, or to CloudFront, or if you have cross stack resource dependencies. That’s not to mention that you could be taking other functions out of service unnecessarily with a full remove, redeploy. Both methods will work, but with a service in production, I would suggest a more targeted approach.

Comment: You sir - are a life saver!

Answer (score 12):

Use sls remove to remove everything from the stack and then run sls deploy

Comment: this deletes everything in Dynamodb, s3, etc!

Answer (score 4):

> Caution: This will delete and recreate the whole stack including Databases if you have any, so try at your own risk

Use following command:

serverless remove --stage "environment" --region "region"

eg.
serverless remove --stage dev --region us-east-1

The point is if you accidently/manually delete anything from the stack then you break the stack. You have to remove it in with above command and clean it up.

Another workaround would be to recreate the deleted component manually but again I suggest go with the above flow and now to break it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your region filter on the menu at the top of the AWS console.

Make sure it's the same as the region you deploy to in serverless.yml:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Can't recall if it was because I changed the function name or because I added

```
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true
```

to serverless.yml in the provider section. (I did this because I wanted to switch to [the new API gateway naming](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#AWS_API_GATEWAY_NAME_STARTING_WITH_SERVICE))

Serverless was still tracking the old name, so in order to reset this and be able to deploy again I did these 3 steps:

1. deleted the bucket that Serverless created in S3;
2. deleted the stack that Serverless created in CloudFormation;
3. deleted the .serverless folder that Serverless created in my project's root folder.

After that, the `serverless deploy` command worked again.