# sls deploy returns 'update_failed' after heavy use

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I've got a stack that has been successfully deployed for several months.  It includes S3 buckets, Dynamo tables, a Cognito user pool, API Gateway, and several Lambda functions.  Periodic updates or adding new functions worked well.  Nice.

In the last week I've been using `sls deploy` much more often as I debug a specific function.  Suddenly this returns `UPDATE_FAILED: {anyFunctionHere}LambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function) Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)" (RequestToken: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)` for random lambdas -sometimes the one I'm working on, sometimes one I haven't touched in weeks.  These functions are not close to the size limit, and the one I'm working on has a single layer attached which, again, is not a big file.  It just seems to happen when a stack is deployed frequently. Almost like there's a build-up that needs to be cleaned?

I tried following the advice here [Serverless deploy - Function not found - sls deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382779/serverless-deploy-function-not-found-sls-deploy) with no success.

I tried going in to the Lambda console and deleting troublesome functions, but that hasn't helped, either. Sometimes I get "Function {name} not found" and sometimes it's another "Unzipped size..." message about an unrelated function.

**How do I move beyond this error and get back to development??**

My serverless.yml file -

```
service: myAbsolutelyFabulousProject

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  versionFunctions: false
  apiName: AbFab
  timeout: 10

package:
  patterns:
    - "!.cache/**"
    - "!.pytest_cache/**"
    - "!.env/**"
    - "!env/*"
    - "!venv/*"
    - "!.venv/**"
    - "!.git/**"
    - "!.serverless/**"
    - "!node_modules/**"
    - "!unit_tests/**"
    - "!integration_tests/**"
    - "!README.md"
    - "!package.json"
    - "!package-lock.json"

functions:
   createNewUsers:
     handler: createNewUsers.createNewUsers
     iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
     iamRoleStatements:
       - Effect: "Allow"
         Action:
           - cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser
           - cognito-idp:AdminAddUserToGroup
           - cognito-idp:AdminRemoveUserFromGroup
         Resource: ${self:custom.pool}
       - Effect: "Allow"
         Action:
           - kms:Encrypt
         Resource: "*"
     events:
       - http:
           path: users/create
           method: post
           private: false
           cors:
             origin: "*"
             headers: ${self:custom.allowed-headers}
             allowCredentials: true
           authorizer:
             arn: ${self:custom.pool}

  decryptMagicBOX:
    handler: decryptMagicBOX.decryptMagicBOX
    iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - kms:Decrypt
        Resource: 
          - ${self:custom.kms}
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - dynamodb:GetItem
        Resource:
          - ${self:custom.abfab_users_table}
          - ${self:custom.abfab_users_table}/index/*
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p38-PyNaCl:1

   getTableData:
     handler: getTableData.getTableData
     iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
     iamRoleStatements:
       - Effect: "Allow"
         Action:
           - dynamodb:Query
           - dynamodb:Scan
         Resource:
           - ${self:custom.abfab_table}
           - ${self:custom.abfab_table}/index/*
           - ${self:custom.abfab_orgs_table}
           - ${self:custom.abfab_orgs_table}/index/*
     events:
       - http:
           path: /reports
           method: get
           request:
             parameters:
               querystrings:
                 tableName: true
           private: false
           cors:
             origin: "*"
             headers: ${self:custom.allowed-headers}
             allowCredentials: true
           authorizer:
             arn: ${self:custom.pool}

  getUserList:
    handler: getUserList.getUserList
    iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - cognito-idp:listUsers
          - cognito-idp:listUsersInGroup
        Resource:
          - ${self:custom.pool}
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - dynamodb:Scan
        Resource:
          - ${self:custom.abfab_users_table}
          - ${self:custom.abfab_users_table}/index/*
    events:
      - http:
          path: users/list
          method: get
          private: false
          cors:
            origin: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowed-headers}
            allowCredentials: true
          authorizer:
            arn: ${self:custom.pool}

  pushFile:
    handler: pushFile.pushFile
    iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action: 
          - cognito-idp:AdminGetUser
        Resource: ${self:custom.pool}
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - s3:GetObject
          - s3:GetObjectAcl
          # - s3:ListBucket
        Resource: 
          - ${self:custom.uploadBucket}/*
          - ${self:custom.uploadBucket}
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - s3:PutObject
        Resource: ${self:custom.resultsBucket}/*
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - dynamodb:PutItem
          - dynamodb:GetItem
          - dynamodb:UpdateItem
          - dynamodb:Query
        Resource:
          - ${self:custom.abfab_table}
          - ${self:custom.abfab_table}/index/*
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - lambda:InvokeFunction
        Resource: "*"
    timeout: 24

  registerNewUser:
    handler: registerNewUser.register_new_user
    iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - dynamodb:PutItem
        Resource: ${self:custom.abfab_users_table}
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - kms:Encrypt
        Resource: ${self:custom.kms}
    events:
      - http:
          path: users/register
          method: post
          private: false
          cors:
            origin: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowed-headers}
            allowCredentials: true
          authorizer:
            arn: ${self:custom.pool}
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-p38-PyNaCl:1

  resendFile:
    handler: resendFile.resendFile
    iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - s3:HeadObject
          - s3:GetObject
        Resource:
          - ${self:custom.uploadBucket}/*
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - dynamodb:PutItem
          - dynamodb:GetItem
          - dynamodb:UpdateItem
          - dynamodb:Query
        Resource:
          - ${self:custom.abfab_table}
          - ${self:custom.abfab_table}/index/*
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - lambda:InvokeFunction
        Resource: "*"
    events:
      - http:
          path: resend
          method: post
          private: false
          cors:
            origin: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowed-headers}
            allowCredentials: true
          authorizer:
            arn: ${self:custom.pool}

  sendFile:
    handler: sendFile.sendFile
    iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - s3:GetObject
        Resource:
          - ${self:custom.uploadBucket}/*

  upload:
    handler: upload.upload
    iamRoleStatementsInherit: true
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - s3:PutObject
          - s3:GetObject
          - s3:PutObjectACL
        Resource:
          - ${self:custom.uploadBucket}/*
    events:
      - http:
          path: upload
          method: post
          private: false
          cors:
            origin: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowed-headers}
            allowCredentials: true
          authorizer:
            arn: ${self:custom.pool}

resources:
  Resources:
    GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Vary: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
        RestApiId:
          Ref: "ApiGatewayRestApi"
    GatewayResponseDefault5XX:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse"
      Properties:
        ResponseParameters:
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Vary: "'*'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "'*'"
        ResponseType: DEFAULT_5XX
        RestApiId:
          Ref: "ApiGatewayRestApi"

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
  - serverless-prune-versions

custom:
  serverless-iam-roles-per-function:
    defaultInherit: true
  pool: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:userpool/us-east-1_ZZZZZZZZZ
  abfab_table: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/ABFAB
  abfab_orgs_table: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/ABFAB-Orgs
  abfab_users_table: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/ABFAB-Users
  kms: arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:key/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  uploadBucket: arn:aws:s3:::abfab-${self:provider.stage}-uploads
  resultsBucket: arn:aws:s3:::abfab-${self:provider.stage}-results
  ses: arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:identity/noreply@nunyabiz.com
  pythonRequirements:
    zip: false
    slim: true
  allowed-headers:
    - Content-Type
    - X-Amz-Date
    - Authorization
    - X-Api-Key
    - Vary
    - X-Amz-Security-Token
    - Origin
    - x-requested-with
    - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    - Access-Control-Allow-Headers
    - Access-Control-Allow-Methods
    - Access-Control-Request-Headers
    - Access-Control-Request-Method
    - Access-Control-Expose-Headers
  prune:
    automatic: true
    includeLayers: true
    number: 5
```

Comment: Update to note sizes:  Each lambda is less that 50 MB  (pretty much all are 46.65 MB) and the layer I use is 1.64 MB, so 2 functions now equal 48.29 MB.